# JavaScript - creating a html table or grid from a list of words in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I take the list of words and create a html table from them?

```
 <script>
   $('.wordcontainer').html('<ul><li></li></ul>');
   var listofwords = {"mat","cat","dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man"};
 </script>
```

Comment: by writing code? Show what you've attempted and we'll try to help fix it, but we're not going to write this for you.

Comment: First of all fix your syntax error

Comment: And, given that input, what should the output be? How many columns, and rows, in the `table`? And why is it tabular, as opposed to a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
var listOfWords = ["mat","cat","dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man"];
var innerTable = '';
for (var i = 0, len = listOfWords.length; i < len; i++) {
  innerTable += '<tr><td>'+listOfWords[i]+'</td></tr>';
}
$('<table>'+innerTable+'</table>').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe change your code for:

```
var listofwords = ["mat","cat","dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man"];
var table = "<table>";
for (var i = 0; i < listOfWords.length; i++) {
   table += '<tr><td>'+listOfWords[i]+'</td></tr>';
}
table += "</table>";
$("body").append(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
var listOfWords = ['foo', 'bar', 'sigma'];
var $list       = $('<ul/>');
$.each(listOfWords, function () { $list.append('<li>'+this+'</li>'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude try to make it on urself . Not every time will u receive help.
Best of Luck

```
<script>
       $('.wordcontainer').html('<ul><li></li></ul>');
       var listofwords = ["mat","cat","dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man"];
       var stringTable = '';
      foreach(var word in listofwords)
      {
         stringTable += '<tr><td>'+word+'</td></tr>';
      }
    $("body").append('<table>'+stringTable+'</table>')
    });
     </script>
```